# How to manage query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query_message23 = "select * from messages_system as m, members as me where m.mes_id='$messageId' AND m.frm_id=me.mem_id";
```

it gives output

```
Array ( [mes_id] => 826 [mem_id] => 334 [frm_id] => 334 [subject] => Re: Re: Re: Re: Re: Hola! [body] => i dno i just made it up lollllllllllllllllllll

Artin wrote:

Haha.. Dooskie??? Is that Russian? lol

aurita wrote:

PFFFFFFT!!!!!!!!!!!
YOU KNOW HOW I DOOSKIE! LMAO!
```

you can see that mem_id and frm_id are the same. How? I am confused. When i run this query in phpmyadmin i get mem_id 48 and frm_id 334 from messages_system and from members table (as i joined 2 tables) mem_id 334, so i think this members mem_id is overriding on messages_system mem_id.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're joining tables and there's two or more duplicate field names in those joined tables, you should use an alias to distinguish them

```
SELECT table1.mem_id AS mem_id1, table2.mem_id AS mem_id2
FROM ...
```

which gives you `mem_id1` and `mem_id2` in your fetched array.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt you get different mem_id and frm_id in phpmyadmin since this is in your where clause :

```
 m.frm_id=me.mem_id
```

I know nothing about your table structure, but it's obvious to me that frm_id and mem_id must be the same in order for the query to return something !

Answer (score 1):

Try only selecting the fields you want,

`SELECT m.mes_id, me.mem_id, m.frm_id, m.subject, m.body FROM` ...

Use `m.mem_id AS m_mem_id` to avoid overwriting fields with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a condition:

```
   ...AND m.frm_id=me.mem_id
```

no wander they are the same.